# Need to set multiple DSN when connecting DB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

It's a DB connecting asp code.

```
Dim db
Set db = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
db.Open ("dsn=book;uid=bookmgr;pwd=bookmgr;")
```

And need to connect to two DSN..(two different DataBase)

but `dsn=book,book_adm;` is wrong and

`dsn=book;dsn=book_adm;` takes effect only the last one.

Creating another Server object variable requires editing lots of asp files..

So I want to avoid that way.. It all started when older database is divided into two..

I googled it.. but found nothing useful..

Please help me out this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access multiple DSNs from a single connection.

If both dsns point to different catalogs (databases) on the same server, you can use the single connection to access both catalogs by including the catalog name in your sql code in the asp files. Otherwise you will need to change the asp code to use 2 connections.